# The URL loaded two times on every page

Tags: joomla-3.x, url

Joomla: 3.3.0

[image: Homepage]
[image: Another Page]

The problem occurs on every page. creact.com is loaded on every page and the real link too.

The htaccess file is modified with these lines:

```
### START WILDCARD ##################
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.creact\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.creact\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://c999.xxxxx.de/?u=%{HTTP_HOST} [L]
### ENDE WILDCARD ###################
```

I have removed these lines, but I had no success. Then I deactivated the redirect plugin with no success. What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is caused by blank src attributes of a few tags:

```
* <script src="">
* <iframe src="">
* <link href="">
* <img src="">
```

Whenever any media/page is referred with a blank source, it requests the current URL.

Imagine that you have `<img src="">` on the page at
http://www.example.com/. The big problem is that each instance of `<img src="">`
makes a request to `/` in all browsers, which is the homepage of
the domain.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a empty <script></script> tag. Problem solved :-)